# How to ensure rST document quality?

Tags: python-sphinx, githooks, restructuredtext

We are now using sphinx+rST to manage our inner documents. But some developers are not abbey to rST format. So I'd like to add a git-hook to ensure the quality of the rST docs. Any rST lint tools available?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/restructuredtext_lint, perhaps?

Comment: There's now https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinx-lint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add https://pypi.python.org/pypi/restructuredtext_lint to your repository's pre-commit or pre-receive hook.

Comment: Except reporting too many false positives of sphinx directives, it works. I am evaluating doc8.